# retrieving automated backup from google sql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I would like to download an automated backup of my google cloud sql, my issue is, I have a client who accidentally deleted some data, and I am hoping using the latest automated backup I can pick and choose which to restore, by either restoring it to a different DB or some janky regex

From the options I see, I can only restore the whole thing.

Is there a way? I am in dire need of this capability.

Comment: one more thing, I am using postgres 9.6

Answer (score 1):

So turns out you can do it by:

1. Creating a new instance (not a new database)
2. Restore this instance to the backup you want